# Counting a number of same words between two columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume that I have the following table in python pandas

```
friend_description  friend_definition
    James is dumb      dumb dude
    Jacob is smart     smart guy
    Jane is pretty     she looks pretty
    Susan is rich      she is rich
```

here, in the first row, the word 'dumb' is contained in both columns. In the second row, 'smart' is contained in both columns. In the third row, 'pretty' is contained in both columns, and in the final row, 'is' and 'rich' are contained in both columns. I want to create the following columns:

```
friend_description  friend_definition      word_overlap    overlap_count
    James is dumb      dumb dude              dumb             1
    Jacob is smart     smart guy              smart            1
    Jane is pretty     she looks pretty       pretty           1
    Susan is rich      she is rich            is rich          2
```

I could use a for loop to manually define a new column with such things, but I was wondering if there's a function in pandas that makes this type of operations much smoother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple list comprehension appears to be the fastest method when working with such strings:

```
In [112]: df['word_overlap'] = [set(x[0].split()) & set(x[1].split()) for x in df.values]

In [113]: df['overlap_count'] = df['word_overlap'].str.len()

In [114]: df
Out[114]:
  friend_description friend_definition word_overlap  overlap_count
0      James is dumb         dumb dude       {dumb}              1
1     Jacob is smart         smart guy      {smart}              1
2     Jane is pretty  she looks pretty     {pretty}              1
3      Susan is rich       she is rich   {rich, is}              2
```

single `apply(..., axis=1)`:

```
In [85]: df['word_overlap'] = df.apply(lambda r: set(r['friend_description'].split()) &
    ...:                                          set(r['friend_definition'].split()),
    ...:                                axis=1)
    ...:

In [86]: df['overlap_count'] = df['word_overlap'].str.len()

In [87]: df
Out[87]:
  friend_description friend_definition word_overlap  overlap_count
0      James is dumb         dumb dude       {dumb}              1
1     Jacob is smart         smart guy      {smart}              1
2     Jane is pretty  she looks pretty     {pretty}              1
3      Susan is rich       she is rich   {rich, is}              2
```

`apply().apply(..., axis=1)` method:

```
In [23]: df['word_overlap'] = (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(expand=False))
    ...:                         .apply(lambda r: set(r['friend_description']) & set(r['friend_definition']),
    ...:                                axis=1))
    ...:

In [24]: df['overlap_count'] = df['word_overlap'].str.len()

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
  friend_description friend_definition word_overlap  overlap_count
0      James is dumb         dumb dude       {dumb}              1
1     Jacob is smart         smart guy      {smart}              1
2     Jane is pretty  she looks pretty     {pretty}              1
3      Susan is rich       she is rich   {is, rich}              2
```

**Timing** against 40.000 rows DF:

```
In [104]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [105]: df.shape
Out[105]: (40000, 2)

In [106]: %timeit [set(x[0].split()) & set(x[1].split()) for x in df.values]
223 ms ± 19.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [107]: %timeit df.apply(lambda r: set(r['friend_description'].split()) & set(r['friend_definition'].split()), axis=1)
3.65 s ± 46.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [108]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(expand=False)).apply(lambda r: set(r['friend_description']) & set(r['friend_definition']),
     ...: axis=1)
4.63 s ± 84.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 3):

One Liner... because, why not?  I was here to upvote @MaxU's answer anyway.  I might as well leave one myself.

```
df.join(
    df.applymap(lambda x: set(x.split())).pipe(
        lambda d: d.friend_definition - (d.friend_definition - d.friend_description)
    ).pipe(lambda s: pd.DataFrame(dict(word_overlap=s, overlap_count=s.str.len())))
)

  friend_description friend_definition  overlap_count word_overlap
0      James is dumb         dumb dude              1       {dumb}
1     Jacob is smart         smart guy              1      {smart}
2     Jane is pretty  she looks pretty              1     {pretty}
3      Susan is rich       she is rich              2   {rich, is}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier to understand for mere mortals (such as me)?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('user98235.csv', sep='\t')
>>> def f(columns):
...     f_desc, f_def = columns[0], columns[1]
...     common = set(f_desc.split()).intersection(set(f_def.split()))
...     return common, len(common)
... 
>>> df[['word_overlap', 'overlap_count']] = df.apply(f, axis=1, raw=True).apply(pd.Series)
>>> df
  friend_description friend_definition word_overlap  overlap_count
0      James is dumb         dumb dude       {dumb}              1
1     Jacob is smart         smart guy      {smart}              1
2     Jane is pretty  she looks pretty     {pretty}              1
3      Susan is rich       she is rich   {is, rich}              2
```